# Gitlab commands should run on X64 version of powershell and not on X86

Tags: powershell, gitlab

`config.toml` file contains below

```
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
```

From gitlab job, when I am executing
`$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` , I am receiving output as `x86`

Because of this certain commands like, `Remove-Website  -Name "test"` does not works

On Same runner, if I execute `Remove-Website  -Name "test"` in X64 version of powershell it works but not on X86 version

Error

```
Remove-Website : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for component
with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered
```

Solution of this error is to execute commands in X64 version of powershell from gitlab jobs. But, then gitlab job is using X86 version of powershell

Comment: Did you check if you are using the x64 executable of GitLab Runner?

Comment: Gitlab runner is of X86, I changed this to X64 and it resolves the issue. Thanks @Marius

Comment: would be nice if you could accept the answer below for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab Runner comes in different builds for Windows: 386 (x86) and amd64 (x64). The different binaries are linked on the [install page of GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html).

The different versions start the respective PowerShell version.

If you want to run x64 powershell make sure that you have downloaded the amd64 version of GitLab Runner. Follow the instructions (Uninstall / Install) on the install page to replace the runner.

Comment: It would help future readers if you spelled out _how_ to do that.